# Updating a line in terminal with python

Tags: python

I'm not sure where to start with this, so even pointing me in the right direction would be helpful. I would like to update a line continuously in the terminal using python but can't figure out how to do this. I'm thinking something like `top` is doing with constantly updated information but not printing new lines.

So simplistically something like this:

```
for i in myList:
    print i #but overwrite previous output rather than putting on new line
```

Comment: [curses](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html) is the classic library to do that, but there are probably better options I'm just not thinking of at present. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can print a `'\r'` (which places the caret at the beginning of the current line) after any output:

```
for x in range(10):
    print x, '\r',
print "\n"
```

You can also add `sys.stdout.flush()` after `print`ing to make the output visible immediately.

Comment: with `sys.stdout.flush()` that does what I'm looking for. Thanks for the help.

Comment: In Python 3, use the `end` kwarg to the `print` function: `for i in range(10): print(i, end="\r")`